# Another user in my network is using my IP and MAC address - what can I do?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, security, ip-address, mac-address

These days I had problem with my internet connection.

I have a static IP connection, but some time ago I couldn't access the internet. A friend helped me and we found out that the IP and MAC-address of my PC were assigned to another user in my network.

This user is using some program which is giving him this precious information of mine (i.e. the addresses). The Ubuntu PC in question is acting like a web server and I need a way (if there exists one) to hide this important information, since I need my server to run all day with active internet connection.

The ISP can't avoid this problem.

Comment: Read this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/237897/how-does-one-prevent-another-server-in-a-subnet-to-steal-the-ip-address-of-our

Comment: *someone* needs to *give up* their static IP. Can you find out why the other user is using a static IP?

Comment: There's not a way to hide the MAC/IP from your end.  The service provider could do it in a couple of ways...but you're indicating that the service provider is being less than helpful.  You could come at the problem another way and use dyndns or something instead of a static ip.

Comment: This connection was not user for a long time. And my solutions are. One: to block the ip with my friend help and hope the user steals somebody else mac/ip. Two: now i use dynamic dns, update 2h, on static ip. Suggest to opt for dynamic dns and dynamic ip?

Comment: Who's paying for the IP? If you're paying, and your friend is stealing it, he's not a very good friend. If he's paying for it, get your own!

Comment: I and my friend are on the same team, the user is in the opposite team.

Comment: Heh, this information is the core of how a TCP/IP connection is set up. Hiding it would give you the same results, inability to connect. Since you don't mention what kind of connection this is, here's a heads up. Broadband connections are provisioned, ie the HMAC is registered with the ISP. In this situation, the non-registered person is stealing. If you are on a system that doesn't work this way, then a home router like Netgear FVS-114 gives you the option of cloning your computer MAC, using the device MAC or possibly entering your own MAC. With this you should be assigned another IP.

Comment: ... Cont. by DHCP. Since it sounds like you have a static IP, not DHCP assigned, your ISP has to come to terms with tracking down the offender or assigning you a new IP. If they won't do it, you need a new ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your situation. try to restart your server.
Scan your network for any open-end connection (Wireless only).
Fix IP slots and registers every MAC to the server (If possible).

Following tools can be used for guarding against the ARP attack

```
 Anti-ARP
 ARP Watch
 ARP guard
 ARP Defender
 ARP Inspection
 X-Arp
 Network Monitor Tools
```

You can see the reference from here http://www.beepthegeek.com/2011/10/arp-spoofing-tools-and-prevention.html